# Submit form through GET and preserve already existing GET parameters

Tags: php, forms

Let's say I have a form that I send via GET:

```
<form method="get" action="/search.php?foo=bar&test=1&something=else">
    <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="day"/>
    <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="link"/>
</form>
```

And after submitting my form and processing the data (which consists of only saving it to a file), the url is changed to:

> search.php?day=test&link=google.com

What should I do so the url becomes:

> /search.php?foo=bar&test=1&something=else&day=test&link=google.com

(*preserving the old parameters that were included in `action` attribute.*)

Answer (score 4):

The form action will change every time and it's difficult to keep the old GET parameters in the form action.

However, you can go with hidden fields.

Try this:

```
<form method="get" action="/search.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar"/>      <!-- Add this -->
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="1"/>        <!-- Add this -->
    <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="day"/>
    <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="link"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing the action before submitting, depending how you're going to submit the form. This can be done if you apply IDs to your texts and either a name or an ID to the form.

HTML:

```
<form id="frm" method="get" action="/search.php?foo=bar&test=1&something=else">

    <input type="text" name="day" id="day" placeholder="day"/>
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" placeholder="link"/>
</form>
```

Then with JavaScript you can run a function and change the form's action:

```
var _form = document.getElementById('frm');
var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
var link = document.getElementById('link').value;

_form.action += '&day=' + day + '&link=' + link;
_form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a hidden input field.

`<input type="hidden" name="name" value="value">`

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting your variables first from get and then want to add into 2nd form you could get this and create input fields hidden with these get values

**Now when you submit form in get url you will get all you desire data**

```
<?php
if($_GET){
    if(isset($_GET['submit1'])){
        $foo = $_GET['foo'];
        $test = $_GET['test'];
        $something =  $_GET['something'];
?>
        <form method="get" action="/search.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="foo" placeholder="foo" value="<?php echo $foo; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="test" placeholder="test" value="<?php echo $test; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="something" placeholder="something" value="<?php echo $something; ?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="day"/>
            <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="link"/>
        </form>
<?php

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First add explicitly the method you want to send the form, in this case GET.
Second add a slash to action route like "/order.php" or "/payment.php" to avoid problems with relative routes.
Third add a hidden input with the value you wan to send through get method to make your code more readble.

I hope this helps you.

```
<?php $row = ['Name' => 'My Name']; ?>

<form action="/order.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?=$row['Name']?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning">
</form>
```

Comment: *How* it can help if they are **already** have  the method explicitly added, as well as a slash to action route, while the hidden input suggestion has been provided 8 years ago?